# UIPageViewController index error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to open 3 `ViewControllers` `("VC1", "VC2" "VC3")` from a `UIPageViewController` but I get errors which I don't understand.
I am not very familiar with x-code yet.

This is my code from `PagingViewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PagingViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate>

@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger index;

@property int defaultIndex;

@property NSArray *viewControllers;
@property UIPageControl *pageController;
@property UIPageViewController *pageViewController;

@property UIViewController *VC1;
@property UIViewController *VC2;
@property UIViewController *VC3;

@end
```

This is the code from "PagingViewController.m":

```
#import "PagingViewController.h"

@interface PagingViewController ()

@end

@implementation PagingViewController



- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {


//    self.index--;
//    if(self.index<0)
//    {
//        self.index=0;
//    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:self.index--];

}
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    //self.index++;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:self.index++];

}
- (UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    return self.viewControllers[index];


}



- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    // The number of items reflected in the page indicator.
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    // The selected item reflected in the page indicator.
    return self.defaultIndex;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self;

    self.index = 1;

    self.VC1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC1"];
    self.VC2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC2"];
    self.VC3 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC3"];

    self.viewControllers = @[self.VC1, self.VC2, self.VC3];

    //self.index = 1;

    //  [self performSelector:@selector(loadingNextView) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0f];

    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:self.viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];

    self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers;

    [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    //NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.VC1];
    //[self setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];


}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

And this is the error report from the console:

```
2014-02-17 18:34:05.560 PageViewC und TableVC-20140217[4493:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0173c5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014bf8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x016eebcc -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 844
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x016ee870 -[__NSArrayM addObject:] + 64
    4   UIKit                               0x00343d7b -[UIViewController _addChildViewController:performHierarchyCheck:notifyWillMove:] + 417
    5   UIKit                               0x00355874 -[UIViewController(UIContainerViewControllerProtectedMethods) addChildViewController:] + 68
    6   PageViewC und TableVC-20140217      0x00002b4c -[PagingViewController viewDidLoad] + 1180
    7   UIKit                               0x00341318 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
    8   UIKit                               0x003415b4 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    9   UIKit                               0x002699fd -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
    10  UIKit                               0x00269d97 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
    11  UIKit                               0x0026a02d -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    12  UIKit                               0x0027489a -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
    13  UIKit                               0x00227cd0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1851
    14  UIKit                               0x0022c3a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    15  UIKit                               0x0024087c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
    16  UIKit                               0x00240de9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    17  UIKit                               0x0022e025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x036e32f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x036e2e01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x016b7d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x016b7a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x016e277c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x016e1ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x016e18db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    25  UIKit                               0x0022badd -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    26  UIKit                               0x0022dd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    27  PageViewC und TableVC-20140217      0x000033dd main + 141
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d7a70d start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Thanks a lot for helping!
Daniel

**UPDATE**

Meanwhile I have set up 'VC1' properly as a class.
And after following the advice to activate the Breakpoint navigator (which I set up as "All Exceptions" 'Break  on Throw') the Run stopped at this line in the main section ('return UIApplication ... see below)

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

    }
```

This is the new error message in the console:

```
2014-02-18 17:23:02.967 PageViewC und TableVC-20140217[5907:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0173c5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014bf8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x016eebcc -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 844
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x016ee870 -[__NSArrayM addObject:] + 64
    4   UIKit                               0x00343d7b -[UIViewController _addChildViewController:performHierarchyCheck:notifyWillMove:] + 417
    5   UIKit                               0x00355874 -[UIViewController(UIContainerViewControllerProtectedMethods) addChildViewController:] + 68
    6   PageViewC und TableVC-20140217      0x00002acc -[PagingViewController viewDidLoad] + 1180
    7   UIKit                               0x00341318 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
    8   UIKit                               0x003415b4 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    9   UIKit                               0x002699fd -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
    10  UIKit                               0x00269d97 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
    11  UIKit                               0x0026a02d -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    12  UIKit                               0x0027489a -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
    13  UIKit                               0x00227cd0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1851
    14  UIKit                               0x0022c3a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    15  UIKit                               0x0024087c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
    16  UIKit                               0x00240de9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    17  UIKit                               0x0022e025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x036e32f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x036e2e01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x016b7d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x016b7a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x016e277c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x016e1ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x016e18db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    25  UIKit                               0x0022badd -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    26  UIKit                               0x0022dd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    27  PageViewC und TableVC-20140217      0x0000335d main + 141
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d7a70d start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Are you sure either VC1 or VC2 or VC3 are not nil? Check them out. Also you can add a Exception Breakpoint to see which line causes the error.

Comment: @EPyLEpSY VC1 had not been set up as a class properly. I have done this meanwhile. Now there is a different error message in the console. I have copied it into my original question as an UPDATE. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The error message says you're trying to insert a nil object. First thing I'd check is whether  the view controllers in the storyboard are set up with the correct identifiers ('VC1'... etc).

Comment: Thanks for your advice! It seems I am on the right track now. However, I cannot understand the new error warnings. (Please see the UPDATE in my original message. Thanks, Daniel

Comment: The error is exactly the same... you are trying to insert a nil object into an array....

Comment: Check All view controllers are not nil.

Comment: @CW0007007 Thanks! How can I find out if the view controllers are not nil?

Comment: Add a breakpoint and single step through checking their values in the debugger ... ?

Comment: Shouldn't the code show where the problem is?  Unfortunately I am still lacking the knowledge to investigate properly.

Comment: The debugger does show you where the problem is. 

 OR put 

NSAssert(self.VC1, @"VC1 is Nil");
After you create it.

Comment: What have you specified in the Identity inspector? If you click on the view controller in the storyboard and look at the Utilities panel to the right, the third item is the Identity inspector, and this should have VC1 as Storyboard ID for the first one.